# Удаление строк из одной таблицы по критерию из другой

Tags: sql

Имею базу данных, в ней таблицу из которой нужно удалять данные. 
Таблица содержит не которые значения, у каждого id(пусть далее этот id будет называться guid) есть несколько значений. 
Другая таблица содержит  guid, здесь этот guid привязывается к id(у каждого id, до 10 guid)
Третья таблица содержит уже конечный список id у которых нужно почистить значения в первой таблички. Можно ли реализовать удаление только на SQL?
Пример таблиц.
Таблица 1:

> ```
> guid product count
> 1       10     1
> 1       12     1
> 2       15     3 
> 2       17     5
> 3       20     1
> 3       21     1
> 4       10     1
> 5       12     1
> 5       15     3 
> 6       17     5
> 6       20     1
> ```

Таблица 2:

> ```
> id   guid    other
> 1     1      info
> 1     2      info
> 2     4      info
> 1     3      info
> 3     5      info
> 3     6      info
> ```

Таблица 3:

> ```
> id    name
>  1    uName
>  2    uName2
>  3    uName3
> ```

Comment: Можно, но пока не приведешь адекватные примеры таблиц, тебе никто не поможет. Я с твоими id/id/guid->id голову сломал.

Comment: привел пример

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я все правильно понял, то Вам нужно удалить данные из таблицы 1, связанные с определенными данными в таблице 3, причем связь осуществляется через таблицу 2?!
В этом случае запрос будет примерно такой:

```
delete 
  from table1
  where guid in 
        (select guid 
          from table2
          where id in (select id from table3)
             );
```